# How do I execute a query?

Tags: mongoose

I want to display the first 10 Users from a database which have the highest "rate". I didn't find in mongoose docs a lot about queries.

I got a User Schema

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema =  new Schema({
firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
lastname: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    required:true
},
occupation: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
county: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
country: {
    type:String,
    required: true,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
rate:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

But in my controller, on my function I do not know how to query the first 10 Users with the highest rate, can you help me? For now I just User.find() cause I didnt find too much on mongoose docs about that, or maybe I didnt know what to search.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
User.find({}, {}, {sort: { 'rate' : -1 }}).limit(10)
.then(result => {
    // do what you want.
})
.catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
```